# How to access root-folder from dockerfile which isn't in root

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a `package.json` in my root folder.
I have another folder in the root: server.
In this `/server` folder I have a Dockerfile so `/server/Dockerfile`
How can I access this `package.json` from my `Dockerfile`?

Setup:

- /source
- /server

  - Dockerfile
- package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a build script which will:

- copy `/package.json` to the `/server` folder
- call `docker build -t xxx .`

There is an [issue opened for requesting support for symlink](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18789)